# RecyclerView cannot be scrolled because of wrong item count from ViewModel

Tags: android, retrofit, android-mvvm

I'm working on a simple app for searching github user (utilizing [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users)). Unfortunately, requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. So you have to work on your own paging mechanism.

This is my simple logic:

```
TOTAL_PAGES = ceil(total_count/30)

if (currentPage < TOTAL_PAGES) {
    currentPage++;
    doSearchUser(who, currentPage);
}
```

E.g you search the user **goreng**

```
https://api.github.com/search/users?q=goreng
```

It yields **total_count** = 33, which means our TOTAL_PAGES is 2.

And some relevant codes:

**MainActivity.java**

```
 private void doSearchUser(String who, int pageNum) {
    totalCount = viewModel.getTotalCount();
    viewModel.setSearchResult(who, pageNum);

    viewModel.getSearchResult().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<User> theList) {
            searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(context, theList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
        }
    });

    totalCount = viewModel.getTotalCount(); // not working. always returns 0 :(
    TOTAL_PAGES = ((int)Math.ceil((double) totalCount/(double)30));
}

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
        searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(context, userList) ;

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                if(!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) && dy != 0) {
                    if (currentPage < TOTAL_PAGES) {
                        currentPage++;
                        doSearchUser(who, currentPage);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**UserViewModel.java**

```
package com.divbyzero.app.githubusersearch.viewmodel;

import android.util.Log;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

import com.divbyzero.app.githubusersearch.api.APIEndPoint;
import com.divbyzero.app.githubusersearch.api.APIService;
import com.divbyzero.app.githubusersearch.response.SearchResponse;
import com.divbyzero.app.githubusersearch.model.User;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class UserViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<User>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private int totalCount;
    private ArrayList<User> savedData = new ArrayList<User>();

    public void setSearchResult(String who, int page){
        Retrofit retrofit = APIService.getRetrofitService();
        APIEndPoint apiEndpoint = retrofit.create(APIEndPoint.class);
        Call<SearchResponse> call = apiEndpoint.getSearchResult(who, page);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SearchResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SearchResponse> call, Response<SearchResponse> response) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                        savedData.addAll(response.body().getItems());
                        //mutableLiveData.setValue((ArrayList<User>) response.body().getItems());
                        mutableLiveData.setValue(savedData);
                        totalCount = response.body().getTotalCount();
                        Log.d("DBG", "OK");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SearchResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("DBG", "Failed: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<User>> getSearchResult(){
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    public void clear(){
        savedData.clear();
        mutableLiveData.setValue(new ArrayList<User>());
    }

    public int getTotalCount(){
        return totalCount;
    }
}
```

Full repo: https://github.com/anta40/GithubUserSearch

My problem is `viewModel.getTotalCount()` intially returns 0 (whereas with the URL above, it should return 33). It takes a while and eventually it will return 33, though. That's why I can't scroll for more items. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start you do `viewModel.setSearchResult(who, pageNum);` That is asynchronous api call. You code doesn't wait result and goes forward, Then you register observer. Then you try to get total count, but api call is not finished yet. That's why you get 0. You need to wait when api call will be finished. It will be finished when your livedata will have new items, right?That is why in method `onChanged` you will have totalCount = 33

Try to do this

```
viewModel.getSearchResult().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<User> theList) {
            totalCount = viewModel.getTotalCount();
            TOTAL_PAGES = ((int)Math.ceil((double) totalCount/(double)30));

            searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(context, theList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
        }
    });
```